# Не выводится последняя строка датагрида в Word

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, interop

Выводятся все строки датагрида кроме последней.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView13.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView13.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    document.Tables[1].Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Range.Text = dataGridView13.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: А вы документ закрыть не забыли? Интероп не так прост, как кажется. Работа с вордом происходит через COM, а это значит куча нюансов по своевременному освобождению памяти. В любом случае, этот код с виду выглядит нормально. Отлаживайте, выполняйте код пошагово. Кстати, а строки в вордовую таблицу как добавляете?

Comment: строки сразу вбиты в ворд, их количество статично, документ всегда закрыт, все процессы в ворда в диспетчере закрываю

Comment: `их количество статично` - быть может одной не хватает в таком случае? Процессы ворда должны закрываться сами. Своевременно вызывайте фукции закрытия ворда и документа. Используйте конструкции `try-finally`, где необходимо.

Comment: строк точно хватает.

Comment: Предположим остаётся последняя пустая, в которой должны выводится значения из последней строки датагрида

Comment: У меня догадки закончились.

Comment: @aepot если догадки закончились, то можно создать датагрид и таблицу в ворде и попробовать записать из датагрида значения в таблицу. Я с вордом никогда не работал, просто предложение

Comment: @Pekor я работал и очень давно, и это еще та жесть. Так что нет, спасибо :)

Comment: я в принципе так и делаю, но всё равно спасибо)